# jQuery: Select nth-child(1) whose class is equal to a specific class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a unique ID `"cn"` to each first `div` element of class `"C"`, like so:

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C" id="c0"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C" id="c1"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

The following works, but only if the first `div` element whose class is `"C"` is the second child element of class `"A"`. However, this may not always be the case.

```
$('.A :nth-child(2)').each(function(index, elem) {
        elem.id = "c" + index;
});
```

Is there a way to target the first child of class `"A"` whose class is `"C"`?

Something like `$('.A .C:nth-of-class(1)')`, I guess.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see my first guess was one you discarded but you can test if it is a C

```js
$("div.A >:nth-child(2)").each(function(i) { 
  if ($(this).is(".C")) $(this).attr("id","c"+i)
});

// NOTE if there are As that do not have ANY Cs you can do this
/*
var cnt=0
$(".A").each(function() {
  var $c = $(this).find(".C").eq(0);
  if ($c.length==1) $c.attr("id","c"+(cnt++))
});
*/
```

```css
#c0 { color:red }
#c1 { color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>

<div class="A">
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

You can also use .eq

```js
$(".A").each(function(i) {
  $(this).find(".C").eq(0).attr("id","c"+i)
});
```

```css
#c0 { color:red }
#c1 { color:green }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>

<div class="A">
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no possibility in CSS to do this with one single selector, but you can first select all class `C` elements and then eliminate those that are not first among siblings. Those that have a predecessor among siblings are selectable with `.C ~.C`. So you could chain a `.not(".C ~ .C")`

Now jQuery supports an extension to CSS selectors, so that you can embed that second exclusion in the main selector with [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('.A > div.C:not(.C ~ .C)')
```

This works with the rest of your code.

```js
$('.A > div.C:not(.C ~ .C)').each(function(index, elem) {
    elem.id = "c" + index;
});

console.log(container.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't aware this even existed. Accepted the answer from @mplungjan, but yours is equally relevant.

Comment: OK, just be aware that the other solution will skip a number for the next `id` if an A-parent happens not to have any C-children. Not trying to be picky (it is an edge case).

Comment: @trincot - I added (quite a bit) more code to handle this issue if present

Comment: Indeed, that deals with it ;)